# How to resolve Branch from LibGit2Sharp.Commit?

Tags: .net, git, libgit2sharp

Given an instance of a `LibGit2Sharp.Commit` how do I work out what `Branch` that exists on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact this Commit may exist on many `Branch`es. It could even be pointed at by `Tag`s or by the `Stash`.

If one want to know all the references that lead to a specific commit, the `.ReachableFrom()` method may fit just that need:

```
IEnumerable<Reference> refs = repo.Refs.ReachableFrom(new[] { my_commit });
```

Should you want to limit the retrieved the references being searched to the local heads only, an overload of this methods accepts a subset of references to work with:

```
IEnumerable<Reference> localHeadRefs = repo.Refs.ReachableFrom(
    repo.Refs.Where(r => r.IsLocalBranch()),
    new[] { my_commit });
```

Then, retrieving a list of `Branch`es can be done this way:

```
IEnumerable<Branch> branches = localHeadRefs
    .Select(reference => repo.Branches[reference.CanonicalName]);
```